# Material AngularJS ngShow and ngHide

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have created tabs in angularjs with material. I am hiding its tabs content from beginning. How can I show content on tab click with some animation.
Some of my codes

```
<div flex="100" class="bookingBox" layout-align="center center" layout="row">
    <md-content flex="35">
      <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-center-tabs>
        <md-tab label="Item 1" ng-click="bookFlight()">
          <md-content class="md-padding ng-hide">
            Item 1
          </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Item 2" ng-click="myb()">
          <md-content class="md-padding ng-hide">
            Item 2
          </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Item 3" ng-click="olci()">
          <md-content class="md-padding ng-hide">
            Item 3
          </md-content>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
```

My code pen http://codepen.io/milindsaraswala/pen/NrRZYV

Comment: I  tried u r code i am just removing ng-hide from all over..i thing is working.

Comment: @RahulPawar Actually I put ng-hide purposefully as initially i want to hide and i want to open it on tab click only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a function this

```
        function showTab(index) {
          var tabsLength = $scope.tabs.length;
          for(var i = 0 ; i < tabsLength ; i++) {
            $scope.tabs[i] = false;
          }

          $scope.tabs[index] = true;
        }
```

and this being called on tab click. I have updated your codepen. I am not sure about your specific requirement, since md-tabs should do this implicitly.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxGqmN